# Beginner to learning OpenGL - what are these OpenGL tools?

Tags: c++, opengl

I would like to start learning OpenGL, to use it in software written in C++ language. The natural thing I do when attempting to learn something new is acquiring proper literature and online tutorials.

With OpenGL however, I got stuck. Different literature and tutorials that I have checked almost immediately mention terms, like :

- Unofficial OpenGL SDK
- GLSL
- FreeGLUT
- SFLW
- GLEW
- GLFW
- others ...

Even though I checked the websites of these tools or wiki entries, I still don't understand things like : what are they actually with relation to OpenGL, why use one and not another, what do they have in common, what are the differences... And probably most importantly, how do I find what I ( don't ) need ?

So I would very much like to hear an explanation on this topic. Reference to a proper online reading is good as well. Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Open Graphics Library** ([OpenGL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL)) is a cross-language, cross-platform application programming interface ([API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface)) for rendering 2D and 3D vector graphics. As such, it only provides means for drawing basic primitives (like points, lines, triangles), but no high-level functionality. Let's work through your list:

- The "**Unofficial OpenGL SDK**"
  This is just a collection of libraries offering some (more or less) often required functionality, like loading image files, or working with 3D objects, or helper libraries for creating and managing OpenGL contexts (it does include some of the other libraries you mention, we're coming to that.) I wouldn't recommend using that [SDK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_development_kit) as a beginner, but just learn the basics and carefully select the additional libraries you want to use.
- **OpenGL Shading Language** (abbreviated: GLSL or GLslang), is a high-level shading language based on the syntax of the C programming language.
  This is not a separate tool, but a central concept of modern OpenGL. You will need it to write your shaders (which are required in modern GL). That's something you definitively have to learn, but the compiler for this language comes with your GL implementation, so this is nothing you have to install separately.
- **FreeGLUT, GLFW, SFLM**
  As I already said, OpenGL is defined platform-independent. One still needs a platform-specific API to actually create the OpenGL contexts and "connect" them to the windows (or whatever "drawables" there are on the platform). OpenGL does not even have a concept of a "window", and as such, also no means for input event handling, detecting window resizes. These libraries implement wrappers for those platform-specific GL binding APIs and the window and event management, so you can just create a OpenGL context and a suitable window without having to care about all those platform-specific details. FreeGLUT and GLFW are quite focused on providing a simple framework for OpenGL development, while SFML is a more generic multimedia framework (also supporting things like audio output) and is capable of creating OpenGL contexts and windows. Other such libraries would be SDL (which is often used for games), or Qt which supports OpenGL widgets.
- **GLEW** is short for "OpenGL extension wrangler".
  This is a [OpenGL loading library](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/OpenGL_Loading_Library). OpenGL is an extensible
  API. As such, features might or might not be present on the machine your application is executed. Furthermore, the way the OpenGL is defined on some platforms, only a certain set of functions is guaranteed to be exported by the libraries. If you need features of newer versions, you have to use the extension mechanism. This means that, instead of directly linking a function at link time, you have to query the function pointers at *runtime* to get access to those functions. To simplify that process, such loader libraries as GLEW do exist. With GLEW, all you need to do is call `glewInit()` and then you can use any GL function as you like (as long as it is supported by the implementation), forgetting about all those details of the extension mechanism.

What you really "need" of this list: GLSL, but that's not a tool. The other stuff is for convenience, but I highly recommend using some platform-independent window and context management library (GLFW is quite lightweight, but it is hard to tell what you will need. For learning OpenGL, GLFW is surely a good choice.) and also some GL loader like GLEW.